# Why is this NOT producing a type mismatch error in VBA?

Tags: html, vba

I'm declaring a variable as an HTMLAnchorElement object which is reserved for html "a" tags. Then I am setting the variable equal to a paragraph tag which should only work for HTMLParaElement objects.  Somehow the variable becomes a paraelement object despite being declared otherwise.

```
Option Explicit

'Turn on references to Microsoft Internet Controls
'and Microsoft HTML Object Libraries before running

Sub qstn()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim el As HTMLAnchorElement

    IE.navigate "www.youtube.com"

    IE.Visible = True

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: Loop

    Set el = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("p")(0)

    MsgBox TypeName(el)

End Sub
```

Comment: This also works the same vice-versa

Comment: possible they both inherit from the same base class, or implement a common interface , which may result in one object being able to hold reference to the other.